# FeignClient 411 content-length

Tags: feign, content-length, http-status-code-411

I use feign client to get an object from my provider with an object query: `doGet(User u);` Then an exception occurs: `feign.FeignException$FeignClientException: [411 Length Required] during [GET] to ...`

This exception does not always happen, sometimes it works well. Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 3):

add to header of the request if you send empty body:

```
Content-Length:0
```

and send empty object json:

> {}

in body of the request